# displaying bar chart on the bottom of html page fails

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, c3.js

I am trying to load geojson data, which I hard coded as variable called sample. Now I want to display a  chart  after clicking on each feature. Below is my code. But it gives the ErrorMessage: feature is undefined.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([55, 3], 5);

 L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

     attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
     subdomains: ['a','b','c']


}).addTo( map );


var trees = L.geoJson(Sample).addTo(map);

trees.on('click', function ( evt) {
        feature = evt.layer.feature;
        $("#chart").empty();

 var chart = c3.generate({
     data: {
         names: {
             data1: 'a',
             data2: 'b',
             data3: 'c',
             data4: 'd',
             data5: 'e'
         },
         // just taken some RANDOM fields to demonstrate
         // how to draw the chart
         columns: [
             ['data1',
             feature.properties.a],
             ['data2',
             feature.properties.b],
             ['data3',
             feature.properties.c],
             ['data4',
             feature.properties.d],
             ['data5',
             feature.properties.e]
         ],
         types: {
             data1: 'bar',
             data2: 'bar',
             data3: 'bar',
             data4: 'bar',
             data5: 'bar'
         }
     },
     axis: {
         rotated: false,
         x: {
             label: {
                 text: 'Your Topics',
                 position: 'outer-middle'

             }
         },
         y: {
             label: {
                 text: 'Your_Values',
                 position: 'outer-center'
             }
         }

     }
 });
```

});

Comment: can you setup jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lazzat/Lhqvpz2s/1/ this is the right link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event layer in the `trees` click handler doesn't have features.  You should add the click handler to each layer:

```
var trees = L.geoJson(Sample, {
  onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('clicked feature', function(evt) {
      console.log('feature=', feature);
      $("#chart").empty(); 
      // generate chart here using feature
      // var chart = c3.generate({...});
    });
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: sorry for asking again, but is there a better way to load geojson data than hard coding the geojson data?

Comment: yes, you can load it via an AJAX request and draw your map/chart when it's finished loading; details are beyond the scope of a comment